# Razor add self containing attributes using "object htmlAttributes" parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to write a MVC control suing : `IHtmlString`

Now in my constructor I want to provide two parameters:

```
 public MyRazorExtension(string id, object htmlAttributes = null)
```

and instanciate it like:

```
new MyRazorExtension("myId", new { @class = "mycsClass", itemScope = string.Empty })
```

but how do I add a self containing attribute?
For example the required attribute or any other self containg attribute without a value?

```
<input required />
```

Comment: Every attribute has a value so why you don't set the value ?

Comment: Aha, in this case required would be a [boolean attribute](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes)

Comment: So I could write it as `required="required"`.  Attribute existence would mean true and absence false, or `required=""`.

Comment: Yes exactly if you write `required="required"` it means its required and if you don't write it means its not required.,